# abstract library for easier socket programming under linux

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I have to program a server client logic for 2 application, with this conditions:

- 1 application only send data and the other application only receives this data
- both are in C++
- the application that receives data is supposed to be multiplatform, or at least present under Mac, Linux and Windows
- i have to exchange just numerical values or a well defined set of structs, the data packets have a deadly simple skeleton structure

I was hoping that there is a library that can help me with this to keep my work simple.

I want to stress the fact that i have to use only the headers like `sys/socket.h` related to socket programming and no other dependecy.

Thanks.

Comment: No other dependency? So where do you hope to find such a library?
If you can use boost, try Boost.Asio: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html

Comment: wouldn't "a library that can help me" count as an "other dependency"?

Comment: @aschepler i have a really restricted support for programming and a really poor set of headers, if i will use other libraries i may not be able to compile this. Sometimes there are some header only library that provides a more abstract level of interaction.

Comment: @Mark something can change if i will be able to access a much more complete set of GNU libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are a bit inconsistent, because normally a library is a dependency.

Libraries fulfilling your other requirements: Boost.Asio, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html, and ACE (adaptive communication environment), http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html.

Comment: i will probably use boost.asio, looks modern and is, most important of all, portable; ACE doesn't look like it's simple to handle.

Comment: I think it's a good choice. Few years ago I used myself ACE for a high performance server project (portable, all sort of Unix's available at that time and Windows) and I was very happy with it. It's a framework, so you need to learn few concepts, but there isn't that many of them after all. There are good books on ACE by Douglas C. Schmidt's available, and example projects included in the package are excellent, in fact I used one of them as a starting point for my project. But it seems Boost.Asio is more popular these days, which is good.

Answer (score 1):

First, the Berkeley sockets interface really isn't difficult to use, though it's perhaps a little crufty by modern standards.  But if you really want something simpler how about text I/O using something like `netcat`, avoiding doing socket level programming at all and replacing it with simple process spawning and piping?  Or make your "deadly simple" protocol a HTTP transaction and use a simple CGI script and curl/wget (or libcurl) on the client?

There are lots of simple ways to move data over the network that don't involve crufty C APIs.  Which to choose depends on what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: considering the fact that there are a gozillions of public repositories can you provide one among them to show a basic and fully working example about this? maybe the easiest solution really is to just use sockets as they are.

Comment: i'm also wondering how the linux sockets can be interfaced with a windows counterpart or with Mac, the other problem that i'm facing is portability.

Comment: The berkeley sockets API is portable.  OS X supports it natively, and the "winsock" API is only mildly different.

Comment: so i can run my server on linux and listen on windows without too much trouble ?

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer poco over boost.asio: http://pocoproject.org/ but it's still going to be dependency!

Comment: does not looks like free stuff ... i have a really simple task to perform, i want to avoid restricted licensing and paying for a library that i will not use completely

Comment: @hthy46vbs: It has the same license as Boost (http://pocoproject.org/license.html), free and unrestrictive. (Although I've no idea how it compares to Boost otherwise, as I've never used it myself)